# installing the newest LittleCMS library in 14.04

Tags: upgrade, shared-library

I use the rawtherapee package and the latest release requires the latest version  LCMS2.7 . I found the code [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/lcms2.html).

Shall I use it (if yes how?) or is there any other way?

Comment: Are you sure you need 2.7. I provide 2.6 in a couple of ppa's for 14.04 but i've also seen a rawtherapee ppa that has both stable & unstable trusty builds that appear to use the default lcms for trusty, ie. - https://launchpad.net/~dhor/+archive/ubuntu/myway If you want a link to ppa with lcms-2.6 ask (haven't looked at whether 2.7 would be ok for 14.04 yet, note that a lot of apps use lcms

Comment: @doug That could be a good answer =)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/lcms/files/latest/download?source=files to get a proper installation, I would not trust that site. Then

```
  cd /home/your_user/Downloads/lcms2-2.7.tar.gz
```

Now

```
  tar -zxvf lcms2-2.7.tar.gz
```

Then

```
  cd /home/your_user/Downloads/lcms2-2.7
```

Then do these next three lines

```
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
```

If that doesn't work (I'm not sure how this file is setup)

Do

```
  sudo sh install-sh.sh
```

You're done!

Comment: sudo sh install-sh.sh does not work:    sudo sh install-sh.sh
 sh: 0: Can't open install-sh.sh

Comment: how would i recompile imagick after installing this?